# Meta package / quick reference for command line string manipulation tools?

Tags: command-line

The latest version of the Scribes text editor lets us select some text, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and then run an arbitrary command. For example, I can run the sort command and the selected text is replaced appropriately.

This is quite useful but I am also not very well-versed in awk and the like. Is there something I can grab that will provide more of these commands like sort? Maybe a package with a whole bunch of handy, task-specific string manipulation commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu (and possibly other distros) ships with a lot of documentation by default. Especially the `info` stuff is very useful, take the time for reading those.

Documentation about text and file manipulation, which also has an extended page on file permissions:

```
info coreutils
```

Use the arrow keys to scroll through the pages (or page up/down). For more commands, press `h` for **h**elp. If you're on a menu item, press `Enter` to navigate to the section.

For a list of help available for `info`, just invocate `info` without arguments.

Almost every command has an own so-called "manpage" (**man**ual **page**), that can be viewed using the `man` command. If you would like to learn more about the `awk` command, run `man awk`. Not all pages are about commands. For example, information about the Linux filesystem hierarchy can be viewed with `man hier`.

Comment: Oh, wonderful! Thanks, Lekensteyn.
For some reason I never thought to check where sort came from.

And I just learned something else: you can use yelp to show man pages, and it does a pretty good job. Searching for info:coreutils gives a document with all the sections laid out very nicely, so I can continue to convince my fear reflex that I'm not using the scary command line :b